# Calculate the sum of the objects in ListNode

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

How I can make a method to calculate the sum of `listOfNodes` objects? I was doing with foreach statement like

```
foreach(int s in listOfNodes)
    sum += s;
```

to get all the nodes but it didn't worked.

It says:

```
Error   1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.List' because 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.List' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'    C:\Users\TBM\Desktop\I\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs   24  13  ConsoleApplication1
```

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List listOfNodes = new List();

            Random r = new Random();
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                listOfNodes.addObjects(r.Next(1, 100));

            }
            listOfNodes.DisplayList();

                Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class ListNode
        {
            public object inData { get; private set; }
            public ListNode Next { get; set; }

            public ListNode(object dataValues)
                : this(dataValues, null) { }

            public ListNode(object dataValues, 
                ListNode nextNode)
            {
                inData = dataValues; Next = nextNode;
            }
        } // end class ListNode

        public class List
        {
            private ListNode firstNode, lastNode;
            private string name;

            public List(string nameOfList)
            {
                name = nameOfList;
                firstNode = lastNode = null;
            }

            public List()//carieli list konstruktori saxelis "listOfNodes"
                : this("listOfNodes") { }


            public void addObjects(object inItem)
            {
                if (isEmpty())
                { firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode(inItem); }
                else { firstNode = new ListNode(inItem, firstNode); }
            }

            private bool isEmpty()
            {
                return firstNode == null;
            }

            public void DisplayList()
            {
                if (isEmpty())
                { Console.Write("Empty " + name); }
                else
                { 
                    Console.Write("The " + name + " is:\n");

                    ListNode current = firstNode;

                    while (current != null)
                    {
                        Console.Write(current.inData + " ");
                        current = current.Next;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                }
            }

        }//end of class List
    }
}
```

Comment: You know `.NET` already has a `LinkedList<T>`. I guess this is some kind of schoolwork project then and you are going to learn about them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to implement `GetEnumerator` in order to `foreach` over something.  So, implement `GetEnumerator`:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    ListNode node = firstNode;
    while (node != null)
    {
        yield return node;
        node = node.Next;
    }
}
```

You can now have your `List` class implement the `IEnumerable` interface too, if you want.

The alternative would be to not use a `foreach` loop, and instead use a while loop, as I did here, or you did in your `DisplayList` method.